# How to pass a variable from a get_context_data def __init__?

Tags: python, django

There are UpdateView and ModelForm, you need to pass a variable from view to form, here is view:

```
class EditBranchView(UpdateView):
model = Branches
template_name = 'branches/edit.html'
form_class=EditBranchForm

def get_context_data(self, *args,  **kwargs):
    context = super(EditBranchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['form'] = EditBranchForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object, request=self.request, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['phones_form'] = BranchPhonesFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        context['form'] = EditBranchForm(instance=self.object, request=self.request, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['phones_form'] = BranchPhonesFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return context
```

and my form:

```
class EditBranchForm(forms.ModelForm):
regions=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) 
owner = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Profiles.objects.all())

def __init__(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditBranchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.pk = pk
    self.request = request
    self.fields['owner'].queryset = Profiles.objects.filter(pid=self.request.user.id)
    self.fields['regions'].choices = self.request.user.organization.organizationtoregion_set.all().values_list('region__id', 'region__region_name')
```

but it give error:

> **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

How should I do it? Thanks

Comment: What line is giving that error?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument handling in `EditBranchForm.__init__` is wrong.  It should be something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')

    super(EditBranchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    user = request.user
    self.fields['owner'].queryset = Profiles.objects.filter(pid=user.id)
    self.fields['regions'].choices = user.organization \
                                         .organizationtoregion_set.all() \
                                         .values_list('region__id',
                                                      'region__region_name')
```

Comment: This means that you trying to create `EditBranchForm` without `pk` argument. Add the second argument to `.pop()` method. I edited the answer.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: You are passing `None` instead of `request` object.